# MySQL: How to group by range and then sub-group?

Tags: mysql

I want group the data of table1 below into shown in table 2. I could able to group by a column but the output I'm expecting is subgrouping!

`Logic: assetScore => >=0 - <=25 -> LOW, > 25 - <= 60 -> MEDIUM' and > 60 -> HIGH
        status => 1 -> Backlog, 2 -> WIP and 3 -> closed`

```
Table-1:

+----+------------+--------+
| id | assetScore | status |
+----+------------+--------+
|  1 |         10 |      1 |
|  2 |         50 |      1 |
|  3 |         32 |      3 |
|  4 |         22 |      1 |
|  5 |         12 |      2 |
|  6 |         14 |      2 |
|  7 |         18 |      3 |
|  8 |         88 |      1 |
|  9 |         65 |      3 |
| 10 |         24 |      3 |
| 11 |         44 |      2 |
| 12 |         66 |      1 |
| 13 |         22 |      3 |
| 14 |         31 |      1 |
| 15 |       36.5 |      3 |
| 16 |         77 |      2 |
+----+------------+--------+

Expected Result:

+--------+---------+-----+--------+
|        | Backlog | WIP | Closed |
+--------+---------+-----+--------+
| LOW    |       2 |   2 |      3 |
| MEDIUM |       2 |   1 |      2 |
| HIGH   |       2 |   1 |      1 |
+--------+---------+-----+--------+
```

So far I have following SQL (only group by assetScore or status):

```
SELECT 
    t.RANGE, COUNT(*)
FROM
    (SELECT 
        CASE
                WHEN assetScore BETWEEN 0 AND 25 THEN 'LOW'
                WHEN assetScore BETWEEN 26 AND 60 THEN 'MEDIUM'
                ELSE 'HIGH'
            END AS 'RANGE'
    FROM device) t
GROUP BY t.RANGE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could simply add 3  case for status and sum the related  values

```
SELECT 
    t.RANGE, sum(t.Backlog), sum(t.WIP), sum(t.Closed)
FROM
    (SELECT 
        CASE
                WHEN assetScore BETWEEN 0 AND 25 THEN 'LOW'
                WHEN assetScore BETWEEN 26 AND 60 THEN 'MEDIUM'
                ELSE 'HIGH'
            END AS 'RANGE',
        CASE when status = 1 then 1 else 0 end as Backlog,
        CASE when status = 2 then 1 else 0 end as WIP,
        CASE when status = 3 then 1 else 0 end as Closed,
    FROM device) t
GROUP BY t.RANGE;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `case` expression to classify ranges and use conditional aggregation on it.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN assetScore BETWEEN 0 AND 25 THEN 'LOW'
            WHEN assetScore BETWEEN 26 AND 60 THEN 'MEDIUM'
            ELSE 'HIGH'
       END AS `RANGE`,
SUM(`status`=1) as backlog,
SUM(`status`=2) as wip,
SUM(`status`=3) as closed
FROM device
GROUP BY CASE WHEN assetScore BETWEEN 0 AND 25 THEN 'LOW'
              WHEN assetScore BETWEEN 26 AND 60 THEN 'MEDIUM'
         ELSE 'HIGH' END
```